# change to next image automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have the following code used for displaying several images changed on hover, but i also would like to add a feature that changes the image automatically if i dont do it manually.

```
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title><br />

</head>

<body>  
<p>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function changeImage(img){
       document.getElementById('bigImage').src=img;

    }
  </script>

  <img src="../Pictures/lightcircle.png" alt="" width="284" height="156" id="bigImage"    
/>
<p>&nbsp; </p>
<div>
  <p>
  <img src="../Pictures/lightcircle2.png" height="79" width="78" 

onmouseover="changeImage('../Pictures/lightcircle2.png')"/>

 </p>
 <p><img src="../Pictures/lightcircle.png" alt="" width="120" height="100" 

onmouseover="changeImage('../Pictures/lightcircle.png')"/></p>

 <p><img src="../Pictures/lightcircle2.png" alt="" width="78" height="79"    

onmouseover="changeImage('../Pictures/lightcircle2.png')"/></p>

 <p>&nbsp;</p>


 </br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What i want to do is automatically change the images displayed using javascript preferrably. How can i do that?

Comment: you can make it with an interval that calls a function to change the pic periodically

Comment: okey can you tell me more. im not any good at javascript unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setInterval to run a function that changes the image src.

```
var x = 0;
var images = new Array("../Pictures/lightcircle2.png","../Pictures/lightcircle.png");
var i = setInterval(auto, 3000);

function auto()
  {
    x++;
    if (x == images.length)
       x=0;
    document.getElementById('bigImage').src=images[x];      
  }
```

Comment: That's up to you.  You could have an array of img links and cycle through that.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorial-using-setinterval-and-settimeout

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a carousel. If so, try this.

Add this to your JavaScript

```
// The list of images you want to cycle through
var imageRotation = [
           '../Pictures/lightcircle.png',
           '../Pictures/lightcircle2.png'
];
// The current image being displayed
var currentImage = 0;
// A variable to hold the timer
var t; 

// Call this to automatically start rotation. Currently set for a 5 sec rotation
function startCarousel(){
    t=setInterval(changeCarousel,5000);
}

// Moves to the next picture
function changeCarousel(){
    // Change to the next image
    currentImage++;
    // If there isn't a next image, go back to the start
    if (currentImage == imageRotation.length) currentImage = 0;
    // Change the image
    document.getElementById('bigImage').src=imageRotation[currentImage];
}
```

Then modify your function to

```
function changeImage(img){
   // Stops the rotation
   clearInterval(t);
   // Assigns currentImage to the image they selected
   currentImage = imageRotation.indexOf(img);
   // Swap the image
   document.getElementById('bigImage').src=imageRotation[currentImage];
   // Start the rotation again in 10 sec
   setTimeout(startCarousel, 10000); 
}
```

Comment: I did that without any response. I changed by changeImage function to what you wrote as well.

Comment: I made a mistake. Oops. I used setTimeout instead of setInterval in startCarousel() and you'll need to remove the quotes and brackets from both setInterval and setTimeout calls. I've updated the code